# Three summations intertwined of a code: counting number of primitive operations & big O notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have the following code: I need to get the big O notation and calculate the number of primitive operations. I know that loops usually corresponds to mathematical summations. Can someone help out clarify how to solve the Big O the following code, knowing the summations?

```java
public static int hello(int[] first, int[] second) { // assume equal-length arrays
    int n = first.length, count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // loop from 0 to n-1           
        int total = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {// loop from 0 to i
            for (int k = 0; k <= j; k++) { // loop from 0 to j
                total += first[k];
            }
        }
        if (second[i] == total) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

So this would be [image]
right? How do you continue from here?

When running the code with n=10, the first loop runs n times i.e. 10 times, a statement at the level of the second loop runs 45 times, don't know what that means in terms of n and a statement with constant time at the level of the inner third loop runs 165 times.

Can someone help me with what type of summations this code would be and how it translates to Big O? Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can you kindly explain a bit how it is done? So Summation [0, j] (constant) is j right? wouldn't the answers include j , k & n? So you go from inside to outside, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum of first n natural numbers and sum of squares of first n natural numbers is given as , 
[image]

You have got the right summation, so solving it 
S<sub>n</sub> = [image]
S<sub>n</sub> ≤ [image]
S<sub>n</sub> ≤ [image]
S<sub>n</sub> ≤ [image]

S<sub>n</sub> translates to number of operations performed by the for loops altogether. 
Time complexity is thus givens as,
**O(S<sub>n</sub>) ~ O(n<sup>3</sup>)**

Comment: Thank you so much for this easy explanation